# React-router-dom Navigate not rendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use a function to verify the user access Token that is stored on the local Storage, if the token is not valid, I want to redirect the user to /login page, but it is not working. It works if I use useNavigate. Below is my code.

```
axios.get(`${REACT_APP_EXPRESS_BACKEND_URL}/authroute/verifyjwt`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth?.accessToken}`,
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res?.data?._id) {
            dispatch(
              userLoggedIn({
                accessToken: auth.accessToken,
                profile: auth.profile,
                user: auth.user,
                timestamp: auth?.timestamp,
              })
            );
             return children;
            }
          else {
            dispatch(userLoggedOut());
            localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
            return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
          }
        })
```

Comment: That is because `Navigate` is a React component and needs to be rendered to the DOM to have any effect. If the `useNavigate` hook works then use that, otherwise I don't know what other issue you may have here.

Answer (score 0):

`<Navigate />` is a React component. It only works if rendered (i.e. it is **directly** returned by a React component).

Talking strictly about your code snippet I would say that the hook should not work either, as hooks must also be called inside a React (functional) component. I assume though that your code, for some reason, is actually inside a React component and you correctly call the hook on the component root. You probably do the same thing with `useDispatch`.

If you necessarily need to redirect in that specific place (and your code is **NOT** inside a React component) you have to use the history API imperatively by using something like `history.push`. If the code is indeed inside a React component then just use the `useNavigate` hook and everything should be ok.

As a side note, it works the same with Redux too. If you need for instance to access the store state outside a React component you will not be able to use `useSelector` as it is a hook and well, must be called inside a functional component. That's when you need to actually import your `store` and imperatively call `store.getState()`.

I mention this as usually network request are handled outside React components and sometimes you might need to access store state.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First make your imports

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

// Add a variable using the useNavigate hook.

const navigate = useNavigate();

// Change this line from this

return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;

// to this

return navigate("/login")

OR

2. import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// Use this

return redirect("/login");
```

Hope this helps you :))

Comment: The [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility function is only valid in Data routers in loaders and actions, not in React components.